# Aplicação inicializar com Windows

Tags: java

Tenho uma aplicação Java desktop, e preciso que ela seja sempre iniciada junto com o Windows (como um serviço do Windows por exemplo). Esta aplicação deve ficar rodando em segundo plano e sempre ficar aberta, pois vai executar tarefas periodicamente utilizando o Quartz.

Gostaria de saber como eu faço para que ela seja iniciada e mantenha-se sempre em execução?
Caso houver alguma falha e a aplicação não for iniciada, como executar um monitoramento para tentar executá-la novamente?
O processo deve ser automático, pois vou gerar o instalador desta aplicação utilizando o InnoSetup e os clientes vão fazer download da aplicação e instalar.

Ja avisando que fiz pesquisas, vi sobre o Java Service Wrapper, mas não sei como fazer ele manter a aplicação sempre rodando e monitorar tb. Gostaria de apenas uma orientação sobre.

Comment: você pode criar uma tarefa agendada no "Agendador de Tarefas", veja como ele funciona crie uma tarefa básica e entenda seus parâmetros, depois você terá criar um arquivo *.bath e/ou *.vbs para especificar os parâmetros para o mesmo ser inserido automaticamente no momento da instalação da sua aplicação em uma máquina de cliente.
Pesquisa na web como fazer backup automático utilizando arquivos *.bath e/ou *.vbs.

Comment: Conseguiu resolver sua dúvida? Alguma das respostas te ajudou?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar uma chave no Regedit(Registro do Windows) através do próprio Java usando o seguinte código :

```
 String valor = "\"javaw -jar " + System.getProperty("usuário.dir") + "\\meuJar.jar\"";
WinRegistry.writeStringValue(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "meu Jar aplicativo exe", value);
```

E se quiser remover depois a sua chave criada para inicializar o aplicativo com o Windows :

```
WinRegistry.deleteValue(WinRegistry.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run", "meu Jar aplicativo exe");
```

Ou você também pode criar um arquivo .bat e colocar este código dentro para criar uma chave e fazer o seu aplicativo iniciar junto com o Windows :

```
javaw -Xmx200m -jar C:\Caminho\para\jarfile\ArquivoJar.jar
```

E também se isto ainda não te ajudou,segue este [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62289/read-write-to-windows-registry-using-java/6163701#6163701).

Answer (score 0):

Você pode criar um serviço no Windows da seguinte forma, na linha de comando, rodando como **administrador**:

```
sc create meuServico binPath= "java -jar C:\to\my\service.jar" start= auto
                             ^^                                      ^
                       espaço||aspas                           espaço|
```

**Preserve** os espaços e as aspas adicionadas, conforme o exemplo acima.

O parâmetro `start= auto` indica a inicialização automática do serviço ao ligar a máquina.